# R to Latex summary table for categorical variables by year

Tags: r, latex, summary, xtable

```
year <- c(2000,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001)
gender <- c("F","M","M","F","F","M")
grade <- c("A","B","C","C","B","A")
df <- data.frame(year,gender,grade)
```

I would like to make a summary table but minimize manual codes and automates the process as much as possible. In my project, I have 170 variables to summarise.
I tried tidyverse group by but didn't get the result that I want.
I will use xtable to move to latex file. (I tried add.to.row but failed to add "Gender" on the first line.)

Here is the outcome that I want.

[image]

Please help me to draw this table. I need the variable names in the table.

Comment: Are you asking for help with coding the summary values, or code to render the latex output?

Comment: coding the summary values is the priority.

Comment: The `tables` packages is an alternative to `xtable` for tables like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pivot_longer` and `summarise` to generate the summary values.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-year) %>% 
  group_by(year, name, value) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  mutate(prop = round(n / sum(n), 3) * 100)

# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   year, name [4]
    year name   value     n  prop
   <dbl> <chr>  <chr> <int> <dbl>
 1  2000 gender F         1  33.3
 2  2000 gender M         2  66.7
 3  2000 grade  A         1  33.3
 4  2000 grade  B         1  33.3
 5  2000 grade  C         1  33.3
 6  2001 gender F         2  66.7
 7  2001 gender M         1  33.3
 8  2001 grade  A         1  33.3
 9  2001 grade  B         1  33.3
10  2001 grade  C         1  33.3
```

You can also get closer to your desired table by joining values in a formatted string, and then using `pivot_wider`:

```r
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-year) %>% 
  group_by(year, name, value) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  mutate(prop = round(n / sum(n), 3) * 100,
         summary_str = glue::glue("{n}({prop}%)")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(name, value), names_from = "year", 
              values_from = "summary_str") 

  name   value `2000`   `2001`  
  <chr>  <chr> <glue>   <glue>  
1 gender F     1(33.3%) 2(66.7%)
2 gender M     2(66.7%) 1(33.3%)
3 grade  A     1(33.3%) 1(33.3%)
4 grade  B     1(33.3%) 1(33.3%)
5 grade  C     1(33.3%) 1(33.3%)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! How would you add the variable name over the value?

Comment: You're welcome.  If you are asking about the cosmetic placement of the grouping variable (here, `name`) visually on the `value` column, that's more related to whatever package you're using to generate the visual output.  The structure of the grouped data itself is rectangular, which is why it is represented as two columns.  (That's why I asked if you needed the summary values or the code to print the latex in my earlier comment - this answer is for your response, "coding the summary values is the priority".

Answer (score 1):

I mentioned in my comment that you can do this in the `tables` package.  Here's an example:

```r
year <- c(2000,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001)
gender <- c("F","M","M","F","F","M")
grade <- c("A","B","C","C","B","A")

# Our table treats the columns as factors, so save them that way
# I'll change the names to the way we'd like them to appear.

df <- data.frame(Year = factor(year), 
                 Gender = factor(gender),
                 Grade = factor(grade))

library(tables)
# write a small function to format the percent values the way you want.
fmtPercent <- function(x, digits = 1) paste0("(", format(x, digits = digits), "\\%)")

# Calculate the table object.
tab <- tabular(Gender + Grade ~ Year * Heading()*(1 + Percent("col")*Format(fmtPercent())),
               data = df)

# Print it as text.
tab
#>                                    
#>           Year                     
#>           2000         2001        
#>  Gender F 1    (33\\%) 2    (67\\%)
#>         M 2    (67\\%) 1    (33\\%)
#>  Grade  A 1    (33\\%) 1    (33\\%)
#>         B 1    (33\\%) 1    (33\\%)
#>         C 1    (33\\%) 1    (33\\%)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

The reason I added the escapes before the percent sign is so that it would print properly in LaTeX.  In PDF output in an R Markdown document it looks like this:

[image]